Looking for instructions to a set which contains bags that have the number 135149 on them
The box is lost. The QR code doesn't work.
I have tried looking up some random pieces online, but can't find them.
It's not the helicopter set. It seems 135149 appears on many bags.
Contains red and yellow flowers, and eyes.
3 bags with mostly red, yellow, and brown pieces.

Also providing a couple of picture will help us to help you ;)
